# Docker run status=exited issue

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm creating the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:current-alpine as builder
COPY /webapp/public/* public/
COPY /webapp/src/* src/
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm","start"]

EXPOSE 80
```

based on this [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV7aa.png).

I'm getting the following output from docker logs: /src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './Configure/ConfigurationPage' in '/src'. Configuration page is a file located [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DFv6.png). What's causing this?

Comment: You did not configure any CMD and/or ENTRYPOINT for your image. It is using the default command from the base image: i.e. `node`. Since this is an interactive command (i.e. needing the `-it` option) and that I guess you are launching your image in the background instead (i.e. with `-d`), your container exits right after the command was launched.

Comment: @Zeitounator the container runs in detached mode, but i still cant connect to localhost:3000 when i try docker run -dt -i -p 3000:80 scatool. any idea why?

Comment: my idea is that there is far too little information about this new situation to take the risk to give a guess about it. Look at your logs, connect to your running container and make sure all expected processes are up, check if the port is opened.... and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70615816/edit) your question with your findings.

Comment: Not a node expert, but I really wonder how your node application can run inside your container if you only rely on the `node` command from the base image which simply opens a nodejs console. Aren't you supposed to add some `CMD` to your Dockerfile to start your app with the container ?

Comment: @Zeitounator ive updated my question

Answer (score 3):

That is expected because nothing is holding the process or terminal for you. (via `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`).

To be able to start container with your current image, try using `-dt` switch which "works" as a `Detached Terminal`.